# How to dynamically assign author to post in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes

I'm creating a WordPress plugin which has a custom meta-box that lists checkboxes of authors and contributors. When checked, the list shows up on frontend at the end of the post. What I need to do is: When user clicks the name of a contributor, it reverts to archives page, but the post isn't listed under the name of that contributors.

How can I update and save a post under multiple contributors so that it is showed under the author's archives page?

This is the custom meta-box callback function and the function which is called when the post is saved:

```
function cd_meta_box_cb($post)
{
    global $post;
    echo'<b> Select the contributors that have contributed to this post: </b>';
    echo '<br><br>';
    wp_nonce_field('my_meta_box_nonce', 'meta_box_nonce');
    global $wpdb;

    $authors=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT wp_users.ID, wp_users.user_nicename 
    FROM wp_users INNER JOIN wp_usermeta 
    ON wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id 
    WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' 
    AND wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%author%' OR wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%editor%'  
    ORDER BY wp_users.user_nicename");

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    foreach ($authors as $author) {
        $author_info=get_userdata($author->ID);
        //$author_role=$author_info->roles;
        $author_first_name=$author_info->first_name;
        $author_last_name=$author_info->last_name;
        if(strcmp($current_user->user_nicename,$author->user_nicename)==0)
        {       
            echo"<input type='checkbox' id='my_meta_box_check' name='my_meta_box_check[]'";
            echo"value=";
            the_author_meta('user_nicename', $author->ID);
            echo" checked disabled>";

            echo"<input type='hidden' id='my_meta_box_check' name='my_meta_box_check[]'";
            echo"value=";
            the_author_meta('user_nicename', $author->ID);
            echo">";
        }
        else
        {
            echo"<input type='checkbox' id='my_meta_box_check' name='my_meta_box_check[]'";
            echo"value=";
            the_author_meta('user_nicename', $author->ID);
            echo">";    
        }
        echo $author_first_name ." ". $author_last_name ." ";
        echo"(";
        echo"<label id='labelid' for='author'>";
        the_author_meta('user_nicename', $author->ID);
        echo"</label>";
        echo")";
        echo "<br />";
    }
}
//save custom data when our post is saved
function save_custom_data($post_id)
{
    global $post,$wpdb;

    $contributor=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_meta_box_check', true);
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) return;
    if (!isset($_POST['meta_box_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'my_meta_box_nonce')) return;
    if (!current_user_can('edit_post')) return;
    if (isset($_POST['my_meta_box_check'])) 
    {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'my_meta_box_check', $_POST['my_meta_box_check']);
        $tablename = $wpdb->prefix.'authorlist';
        $wpdb->insert($tablename,array('authorname'=>$post_id,'authorpost'=>$contributor));
    }
    else 
    {
        delete_post_meta($post_id, 'my_meta_box_check');
    }
}

add_action('save_post', 'save_custom_data');
```

Comment: This plugin might help you - https://wordpress.org/plugins/co-authors-plus/.

Comment: No I'm trying to create my own plugin, guess I should've mentioned that.

Comment: Then it might be complicated. You can achieve by using custom fields - but you need to override author query with the custom field meta value.

Comment: I need to do something like CoAuthors plugin...I looked at the code but it is too complicated for me :(

Comment: Are you able to achieve authors list meta-box? I'll then try to give you override query for authors page.

Comment: Yes, I can successfully save my custom meta-box and display list of contributors on front-end at the end of each post.

Comment: Okay, can you let me know the meta key or post your meta-box code here?

Comment: I've updated my question with the code...please check it out

Comment: Okay, can you try my updated answer and let me know whether it works?

Comment: well now it shows all the posts by the original author of the post and not the ones which contributor has contributed to.

Comment: You are saving author name (I misunderstood as ID), can you again update the code in my answer and let me know?

Comment: That works brilliant! Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your theme's 'functions.php' or plugin.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'modify_author_query' );

function modify_author_query( $query ) {
    // check if on front-end and author query is modified
    if ( ! is_admin() && is_main_query() && $query->is_author() ) {
        $author_name =  $query->query_vars['author_name'];
        //$userdata = get_user_by('slug',$author_name);
        //$userid = $user->ID;

        $meta_query = array(  
            array(
                'key' => 'my_meta_box_check',
                'value' => $author_name,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        );
        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );

        // unset the default author since we are using custom meta
        unset( $query->query_vars['author_name'] );
    }
}
```

Please note that above may show wrong results if part of a user name matches with another - try saving the data as **comma separated string** (should begin and end with comma) and replace `'value' => $author_name` with `'value' => ','.$author_name.','`.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without changing the theme's function.php file because I'm creating a plugin?

Comment: You can add this in your plugin too.

Comment: Yes I added it to my plugin, but its not working. If I click on a contributor, it gives me its archive page but its not listing the post under which it is a contributor.

Comment: In the meantime, can you let me know the sample of `my_meta_box_check` meta whether it's single array?

Comment: Yes, it returns a single array containing the values of checked checkboxes, i.e. the contributor names.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first off Wordpress is intend to have one author in a post. So we need to start from there.

My approach would be just use the Wordpress author field as the main author and have my own field for 'secondary' authors.

This way you can just hook up to author page queries and add, besides posts where the user is the author, posts where the user is saved under your meta.

Not quoting any code since your problem seems to be more of a wrong approach than not-knowing-code.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('posts_where', function($where){
      if(!is_admin() && is_author() && is_main_query() ){
            $where = "AND ((dev_posts.post_author = ".get_queried_object_id().") OR ( ( dev_postmeta.meta_key = 'auth_id' AND dev_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%:\"'.get_queried_object_id().'\"\;%' ) )) AND dev_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (dev_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR dev_posts.post_status = 'private')";
    }
    return $where;
});

add_action('pre_get_posts', function($query){
    if(!is_admin() && is_author() && is_main_query() ){
        $query->set('relation', 'or');
        $query->set('meta_query', array(array(
            'key' => 'auth_id',
            'value' => ':'.get_queried_object_id().';',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )));
    }
});
```

"dev" is my db prefix so you need to replace with $wpdb->prefix